# Linux still sees drive with old stats

Tags: linux, disk, storage, iscsi

I have Linux vm which is hosted on Hyper-V that has attached ISCSI drive over the network shared from NAS device. Last night I mounted the volume using `mount /dev/sdb /mydrive` pasted some files, unmounted the drive and expanded It's storage using the NAS tools. Problem is that Linux still sees the old size, Windows and the NAS device are both showing the right new size. 
What can I do to resolve this?
Output of `fdisk -l` is the right size (2gb) but `df` is still showing old size (1gb).

Comment: Does it work to run `partprobe` with elevated permissions (as root or with sudo)?

Comment: Actually resize2fs /dev/sdb solved the issue, this however increased the size of the disk, not the partition that I wanted to expand.